# casting count not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
declare @var1 float
declare @var2 float

set @var1=sum(10)
set @var2=count(750)

select cast(@var1 as float) / cast(@var2 AS float)
```

query above returns the value 10 but the correct answer should be 0.0133. Why the casting is not working here?

I'm getting @var1 and @var2 values using sum and count from another query. 10 and 750 are dummy values here.

Comment: That's because `count(750) = 1` so `10/1 = 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working as it should. `count` of a single value will be `1`

So dividing `10/1` will result `10`

```
declare @var1 float
declare @var2 float

set @var1=sum(10)
set @var2=count(750) -- will return 1

select cast(@var1 as float) / cast(@var2 AS float) --10
```

if you want `0.0133` then remove the `count`

```
set @var1=sum(10)
set @var2=750 

select cast(@var1 as float) / cast(@var2 AS float) -- 0.01333
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `count(750)` is `1`.

`count` counts records, not the value in the `()`